# sys_context inconsistencies between databases

Tags: plsql

I have a simple code using sys_context which is giving me diff results between 2 diff databases that have the same data:

Here a sample code:

```
alter session set current_schema = <schemaX>;

DECLARE

   v_schema_name     varchar2(128);
   v_constraint_name varchar2(128);
   
BEGIN

    dbms_output.put_line('---------------------------------------------------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('------------ Restricting using sys_context --------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('---------------------------------------------------------');


    BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line(sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA'));
           SELECT constraint_name
            INTO v_constraint_name
            FROM all_constraints
            WHERE table_name        = <table name>
            AND owner               = sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA')
            ;
            
            dbms_output.put_line(v_constraint_name);
    EXCEPTION
        when others then
            dbms_output.put_line('Error raised : '||sqlerrm);
     
    END;
    
END;
```

I ran in 2 different instances :

```
Results in Instance 1:
---------------------------------------------------------
------------ Restricting using sys_context --------------
---------------------------------------------------------
AE9_COMPANY_TRN
Error raised : ORA-01403: no data found

Results in Instance 2: (THIS IS WHAT IS EXPECTED)
---------------------------------------------------------
------------ Restricting using sys_context --------------
---------------------------------------------------------
AE9_COMPANY_TRN
Error raised : ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

Why instance 1 is returning different results?

Comment: I don't think the issue is SYS_CONTEXT, since it's returning the same value each time - AE9_COMPANY_TRN. It looks like the same table has a different set of constraints on each database. Run the data dictionary query against outside of the PL/SQL block to view the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your instance1's table `AE9_COMPANY_TRN.<table name>` has no constraints while your instance2's table `AE9_COMPANY_TRN.<table name>` has more than one constraint.

In other words: You have different versions of your data model deployed in `AE9_COMPANY_TRN` schema on your instance 1 vs instance 2.